# NumberFormatException in Drill SQL while casting to BIGINT when its actually a number

Tags: sql, hadoop, apache-drill

In the following SQL, drill cribs when trying to convert a number which is in varchar

```
select cast (case IsNumeric(Delta_Radio_Delay)  
when 0 then 0 else Delta_Radio_Delay end as BIGINT) 
from datasource.`./sometable` 
where Delta_Radio_Delay='4294967294';
```

BIGINT should be able to take very large number. I dont understand how it throws the below error:

> Error: SYSTEM ERROR: NumberFormatException: 4294967294
>       Fragment 1:29
>       [Error Id: a63bb113-271f-4d8b-8194-2c9728543200 on cluster-3:31010] (state=,code=0)

How can I modify SQL to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In apache drill **BIGINT has only 8 bytes**. So you can only use number between, -2147483648 and 2147483647.

ie: maximum number will be '**2147483647**'. That's why it throws the error.

Hope it helps you.